# How to say "to cause a problem" in japanese?

Tags: translation, phrase-requests

I wonder if there usual/fixed phrase to say "to cause a problem"? I find self-made 問題を起こす to be inappropriate/unnatural in some way...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By far the most commonly used expressions would be:

- 「～～が問題{もんだい}**を**引{ひ}き起{お}こす」 and
- 「～～が問題**の**原因{げんいん}となる」

Neither one would be any better than the other.

To introduce a more formal way of saying this, we also say:

- 「問題**は**～～**に**起因{きいん}する」

With this expression, the grammatical subject is the "problem".  It is not the thing/phenomenon/person as in the first two expressions listed at the top.

Regarding your phrase 「問題を起{お}こす」, it is indeed a very common and natural-sounding verb phrase.  It is, however, closer to "**to create a problem**" in meaning than to "**to cause a problem**".